# How do I make a shorter .wav file loop over and over while a longer .wav file continues playing?

Tags: python, audio, jython, wav

This is for a class. The professor asked that we combine two wav files of different lengths and if the foreground file is longer than the background, we are asked to make the background continue looping while the foreground wav file continues playing. I've managed to combine them but all my attempts at creating a loop for the background to continue playing have been futile. Also no modules are allowed.

```
def main():
  #open and make fg "foreground" sound
  openFileName = pickAFile()
  fgsound = makeSound (openFileName)

  #open and make bg "background" sound
  openFileName2 = pickAFile()
  bgsound = makeSound (openFileName2)

  finalsound = combineSounds (fgsound, bgsound)

  explore (finalsound)


def combineSounds(fgsound, bgsound):
  sampleList1 = getSamples(fgsound)
  sampleList2 = getSamples (bgsound)

  fglength = getLength (fgsound)
  bglength = getLength (bgsound)



  for i in range(fglength):

    amp1 = getSampleValue (sampleList1[i])
    amp2 = getSampleValue (sampleList2[i])
    amp2 = ((amp2)/3)

    if amp2 > bglength:
      amp2 = (bglength * i) - amp2 

    amp3 = amp1 + amp2

    if (amp3 > 32767):
      amp3 = 32767
    elif (amp3 < -32768):
      amp3 = -32768


    setSampleValue (sampleList1[i], amp3)
```

Comment: Why the java tag for your question? I don't see any Java code posted.

Comment: Sorry, fixed. It's because the language is Jython. So some Jave "rules" sometimes apply in this class.